# Why is google Drive API is not allowing to delete a folder for user who has "can edit" access and not the owner of the folder

Tags: api, google-drive-api

My Website integrates the GoogleDrive API.

When a Folder is being shared with my website and certain people are given "can edit" right to the folder and certain "can view" right. So people with "can edit" access can add folder/files to the main shared folder.Below is an example of the shared folder.

All `test/test1/test2`  has "can edit" access on below listed folders. When `test2` try to delete the folder `Folder 2` this action is not happening from the my website UI. Then i tried this deletion from the [GoogleDrive API](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v2/drive.files.delete) explorer, same response i.e `test2` cannot delete  `Folder 2` even though he has 'can edit' access. But when `'test2'` goes to the Google Drive UI he can delete the `Folder 2`, and that action(from his GD UI) actually deletes the folder from the Google Drive UI of the other people who had access to the folder. **Why is the deletion behavior different in google Drive UI and Google Drive API?**

My Scope :https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive

```
-Folder 1 |test is Owner|
  -Folder 2 |test1 is owner| [Delete]
    -Folder 3 |test2 is owner| [Delete]
```

In the code i am using below DELETE REST API call to delete a file or folder.

DELETE https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0Brjfj83jejeii83

[image]

Note: A user can delete a folder/file owned by him from my Website UI using  the above Delete Rest API call.

IS their a way to delete the files/folders from Google Drive API by a user who is not the owner of the file/folder but has "can edit" to it? Is this possible at all? as i see that GoogleDrive API explorer is the only way to check if certain action is supported by DriveAPI. In This case api explorer is behaving as my website does.  why is this behavior is  different in the Google Drive UI?

Comment: what scope is your app using? are you getting any error message back from the deletion attempt? is the folder empty?

Comment: this is my scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive. i am not getting error say that this action is unsuccessful. No the folder is not empty.

Comment: I see that in case of successful deletion of the file and unsuccessful response from the Google is same. Which tell me that every thing went fine and then i run a java script call in my UI delete the file reference. But after a browser refresh i see all the deleted folder and file back as this file were not actually deleted from the Google

Comment: Can you paste the http call and response for the delete. Are you posting to Trash, or deleting? What happens if you delete the files first and then the folder?

Comment: I have the http POST call/response posted. I am actually posting Delete and not trashing. We don't have the option given to delete the main shared folder( i.e Folder 1). we have that option enabled for all the other folders in the list. Deletion of first file and then folder - 1) if that person don't own( but has edit rights) the file/folder don't delete anything. 2) if that person is owner of that file/folder actually deletes the file/folder

Comment: @pinoyyid In this link https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-sharing#roles I see clearly written that users with writer access they are not allowing the Deletion of folder/file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you found, when it comes to the Drive API, you can only delete a file if you have ownership of that file. A lot of Drive API calls on shared files will result in a 403 error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "userAccess",
    "message": "The authenticated user does not have the required access to the file **file id here**",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The authenticated user does not have the required access to the file **file id here**"
 }
}
```

Plan accordingly and make sure your error handling (if receiving errors as the one above) accounts for these things.

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-sharing#roles

Comment: i have seen if nested folder with multiple owner ship on those folders, if the owner of the folder try to delete his folder then all the inner folder also getting deleted even though he is only has "writer" access on the other folders. I don't see any 403 errors